# Turn off whitespace highlight

Tags: webstorm

How do you turn this off?
Ive tried turning off all html highlighting, but it now hightlights all instead of this.

[image]

It's very annoying, it highlights till the end.

Comment: I found the answer in a quick Google search on the first page.

Comment: that is? please not that this is a js file. not an html file

Comment: Doesn't matter. Come on, spend ten seconds searching. You can likely answer this yourself if you can verify that it works.

Comment: if you mean language injection, it also doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it,

File/Preferences > Settings > Search for Injected Language Fragment and then untick the background color.